# WooCommerce conditional variations and attributes

Tags: woocommerce, product-variations

I'm having a buy one get one for free variation offer plus the original 1 piece price.
I need a custom variation to show only if the customer chooses the "buy one get one" to show an extra color and size variation for the free item.